# Library not loaded: @rpath/SDL.framework/Versions/A/SDL on mac 10.9

Tags: xcode, macos, sdl

I have a library project built with xcode3.2.6. It works fine until I tried it on one of the mac 10.9 machine.

The library uses sdl framework.

When I tried my library, I got error message:

```
 Date/Time: 2014-07-02 11:36:04.493 -0400
 OS Version: Mac OS X 10.9.4 (13E28)
 Report Version: 11
 Anonymous UUID: AD396161-ACA4-007D-DB07-036ED3718A4A

 Crashed Thread: 0

 Exception Type: EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
 Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000

 Application Specific Information:
 dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries

 Dyld Error Message:
 Library not loaded: @rpath/SDL.framework/Versions/A/SDL
 Referenced from: /Applications/Eyelink/*/gcwindow.app/Contents/MacOS/gcwindow
 Reason: no suitable image found. Did find:
 /Library/Frameworks/SDL.framework/Versions/A/SDL: no matching architecture in universal   wrapper

 Binary Images:
 0x7fff62313000 - 0x7fff62346817 dyld (239.4) <042C4CED-6FB2-3B1C-948B-CAF2EE3B9F7A>  /usr/lib/dyld
 0x7fff915b8000 - 0x7fff915b8fff com.apple.Cocoa (6.8 - 20) <E90E99D7-A425-3301-A025-D9E0CD11918E> /System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Versions/A/Cocoa
```

I guess the error is related with rpath, but have no idea where I should start debugging  it. Please help. Thanks.

By the way, the SDL version is 1.2.14, include both 32bit and 64bit versions.

The mac is 10.9.4, 64bit.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone finding this in 2020, make sure to install SDL2 correctly for your target system:

https://www.libsdl.org/

In regard to Mac OS X: `/Library/Frameworks/` should contain `SDL2.framework`.

Comment: I already add `SDL2.framework` on my `/Library/Frameworks/` but still didnt work

Comment: A lot changes in almost three years.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Solution for problem]

In "TARGETS", go to "Signing & Capabilities" and check "Disable Library Validation" for all